# Como hacer que una propiedad computada con una llamada axios devuelva un valor

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

Tengo una propiedad computada de la siguiente forma:

```
private get ChangeGroup(): IResults[] {
    Axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URI + 'results?GroupNumber='
    + this.selected,
    {withCredentials: true})
    .then(data => {
        this.items = data.data;
        let i = 1;
        this.items.forEach(
            (e: IResults) => {
                e.position = i;
                i++;
            }
        );
        return this.items; <----- 2
    })
    .catch(error => {return []}); <--- 1
}
```

Esta escrita de esa forma, porque la aplicacion usa typescript, entonces es necesario que la funcion devuelva algo.

En la linea marcada  como 1, devuelve vacio.
En 2, vuelve lleno.
Pero claro, el problema es que esta llamada async vuelve automaticamente. Entonces, como se hace para que esto espere hasta que la llamada vuelva realmente, y tenga algo para devolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR;**

No se puede de forma trivial. Las propiedades computadas son sincronicas y se ejecutan en el momento que se necesitan, porque VUE las cachea para no tener que volver a calcularlas si las variables que contiene son reactivas.

**Explicación y alternativas**

Existe el componente [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed), el cual permite utilizar las variables computadas asincronicas. Sin embargo, este metodo no es compatible con typescript, ya que implica pasar su definición a typescript, lo cual esta explicado en el manual de VUE.

Pero no esta explicado por ningun lado como hacer para definir en el modelo de objetos de vue un nuevo tipo de declaracion interna.

Por lo tanto, aunque dicho objeto se puede usar sin Ts, no sirve para este caso.

La solucion trivial, es usar un watch, que controle la propiedad que se esta cambiando, y cuyo resultado se guarde en otra propiedad, la cual si puede ser cambiada asyncronicamente.

Evan explica en este [thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4083) que aunque esta libreria es una buena idea, y que inclusive podria ser agregada en el framework, pero luego recaen en que seria extender demasiado la base, que siempre trata de ser limpia, y dejan que la libreria evolucione por si sola.

Agregue en un thread donde se le pregunta al autor original del componente como usar esto con Ts, una [pregunta](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed/issues/25#issuecomment-401569741) para saber si habian logrado incluir esto en un componente de clase de VUE.

La solucion a este momento, entonces queda como:

```
public selected: number = 0;
....
@Watch ('selected')
private ChangeGroup() {
    Axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URI + 'results?GroupNumber='
    + this.selected,
    {withCredentials: true})
    .then(data => {
        this.items = data.data;
        let i = 1;
        this.items.forEach(
            (e: IResults) => {
                e.position = i;
                i++;
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Donde selected es la variable reactiva que dispara este evento. En el caso de ejemplo (y aca tambien) es la variable que se usa para hacer el request. Si sirve para el caso, es un cambio de seleccion en un combo.